# getting a value from a callback function

Tags: javascript, function, callback, anonymous

I'm trying to return a value from a callback function and assign it to a variable, though am struggling to work it out - any help would be really appreciated....

```
var latlng1;

function getLocation(){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (function (position){
    coords = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
    callback();         
  })
}

//how can I assign the coords value from the callback to variable latlng1 with global scope?
getLocation (function(){
  //alert(coords);
  return coords;
})

// -----------
//I'm trying something like this....but no joy
latlng1 = getLocation (function(){
  return coords;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm confused as whether or not you want the callback to have access to the `coords` value or to simply return it from the `getLocation` function.  If it's just to have `coords` available to the callback then pass it as a parameter.

```
function getLocation(callback) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (function (position){
    var coords = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
    callback(coords);         
  })
}

getLocation (function(coords){
  alert(coords);
})
```

On the other hand if it's to have it assigned to the return of `getLocation` then that's not possible.  The `getCurrentPosition` API is asynchronous and hence you can't synchronously return it from the `getLocation` method.  Instead you need to pass the call back which wants to use `coords`.

**EDIT**

OP said they just want the `coords` value in `latlng1`.  Here is how you accomplish that

```
var latlng1;
function getLocation() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (function (position){
    var coords = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
    latlng1 = coords; 
  })
}
```

Note though that this doesn't change the asynchronous nature of the API.  The variable `latlng1` won't have the `coords` value until the async call completes.  Because this version doesn't use a callback you have no way of knowing when that completes (other than checking `latlng1` for `undefined`

Comment: Ideally I want to assign the coords value to variable latlng1, rather than just having it available to the callback

Comment: instead of `var coords =` just do `latlng1 = `

Comment: @user1325164 if that's the case then you can assign into `latlng1` instead of doing a callback.

Comment: What I was wanting to achieve was to call getLocation multiple times, assigning the coords to latlng1, latlng2 etc... then to do some comparisons on the latlng values... obviously not hinted at in my question! to be honest, I've just been struggling in getting the coords value into a global scope variable to begin with. I knew the issue was due to asynchronicity (if that a word), but just not how to deal with it. I think I need to revisit the general logic of what I'm trying to achieve. Cheers again.

Comment: I think you may want to look into promises, if you want to get multiple locations and then compare them, you can make promise the fires when both asyc events of getting the locations are complete.

Comment: In looking at quite a few places for ways around this, would it be possible to use jQuery's `$.Deferred`?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var latlng1;

function getLocation(){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (function (position){
    latlng1 = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
    callback();         
  })
}

getLocation (function(){
  alert(latlng1);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass coords to the callback call, and define a parameter for it in the callback. It's easier to read than to try to explain:

```
var latlng1;

function getLocation(callback){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (function (position){
    coords = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
    callback(coords);         
  })
}

//how can I assign the coords value from the callback to variable latlng1 with global scope?
getLocation (function(coords){
  //alert(coords);
  return coords;
})
```

Comment: Thanks Tuan, but thats essentially what I'm already doing (bar explicitly referencing 'coords' in the callback call and argument)

Comment: The `getLocation` function is correct, but the call is not.  getLocation just throws away the return when it does `callback(coords)`.